# Writing optimized React functional components

Tags: reactjs

It is my understanding that the entire React Functional Component gets re-run when re-render is needed or there are any state updates, so how to properly manage the state inside these functions? Is it important to keep it empty of any members like event handlers that you wouldn't want to be re-created every time the function gets re-run?

Is there some sort of best practice for writing optimized functional components?

Comment: I recommend reading through the hooks documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

As how I get it, You want to know how to manage or improve your react performance right? You are right every Component in react gets re-rendered when there are any state changes in this component or in the parent component (if there is).

So there is a tool (Chrome extension) that helps you finds out which part of the application get re-rendered whenever you make an action [React developer tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

**React Memo is something you might be looking for.**

> React.memo(...) is a new feature introduced in React v16.6. It works
>   similiar to React.PureComponent, it helps control functional
>   components re-renders. React.memo(...) is to functional components
>   what React.PureComponent is to class components. How do we use
>   React.memo(…)?

It is very simple. Let’s say we have a functional component, like this:

```
const Funcomponent = ()=> {
    return (
        <div>
            Hiya!! I am a Funtional component
        </div>
    )
}
```

We simply pass the FuncComponent as argument to React.memo function:

```
const Funcomponent = ()=> {
    return (
        <div>
            Hiya!! I am a Funtional component
        </div>
    )
}
const MemodFuncComponent = React.memo(FunComponent)
```

**React.memo returned a purified component MemodFuncComponent.** This component is what we will render in our JSX markup. Whenever the props and state changes in the component, React will check if the prev state and props and the next props and state are equal if not equal the functional component will re-render if they are equal the functional component will not re-render.

**As for second question, yes it's true.** You should avoid defining the function inside the `render` function or in case of functional components, avoid defining inside the function, it will cause unwanted calling of those functions and can result in unwanted behavior as well as cause it to be created every time the component re-renders.

The same goes for adding in-line callback functions for event handlers. They should be defined outside the `render function`.